# Permanent f.lux

Tags: screen, redshift, f.lux

I want F.lux enabled at all times, not only during the night.

I also installed Redshift, it has the same limitations of checking my latitude.

The Windows version of F.lux has always-on functionality, no idea why Linux doesn't.

How do I do this? Or
Is there another software I can use that darkens and eliminate the blue light from my screen? 
I already did the Antarctica attitude trick, but I want something simpler and more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what exactly was your problem? I have Redshift enabled with custom values for day and night, but you could also set day and night to the same value, thus have the same setting all the time.

I see no differences here in configuring Redshift on Linux and f.lux on Windows, except that you can use a GUI on Windows which many users prefer over editing its configuration file/registry on Windows.

Example for the same value for day and night:

```
$ grep -v "^;" .config/redshift.conf 
[redshift]
temp-day=3400
temp-night=3400
transition=1
location-provider=geoclue2
adjustment-method=randr

[manual]
lat=xx.xxxx
lon=xx.xxxx
```

Edit: `transition=1` doesn't make much sense, probably set it to 0 when there is nothing to transition to, except when starting up.

Answer (score 2):

> I want F.lux enabled at all times, not only during the night.

F.lux for Linux does not have an "always on" feature. However, there is something you can do.

Set your location to the North Pole (90.0, 0.0) for the winter half of the year in the Northern Hemisphere, like now.

During the winter half of the year in the Southern Hemisphere, set your location to the South Pole. (-90.0, 0.0)

Since it is always dark at the poles during winter, f.lux will always be on.